# is cURL part of the original PHP installation?

Tags: php, curl, installation

When I first installed PHP did it include the libraries for cURL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To test if your version of PHP has cURL support create a php file:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you open this file in your browser, it will print out all the information regarding your php installation, including whether cURL is enabled.

Look for a line that says cURL support enabled, under a heading curl.

Comment: I indented your code snippet to allow it to be displayed.  For future reference, there's a preview below the edit box :).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not enabled by default.

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php):

> To use PHP's cURL support you must also compile PHP --with-curl[=DIR] where DIR is the location of the directory containing the lib and include directories. In the include directory there should be a folder named curl which should contain the easy.h and curl.h files. There should be a file named libcurl.a located in the lib directory.

However, the Windows distribution includes the built module (`php_curl.dll`), but I believe it's not enabled by default in `php.ini`.